# Error in tableView reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

when i try to refresh my table view,that it's inside a view controller, compiler found an error.
I declare my tableView in .h file and i linked it with the outlet,so why?thanks.

.h

```
@interface UfficiViewController : ViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchDisplayDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate>
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView* tableViewUffici;
@end
```

.m

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {


    self.tableViewUffici.delegate = self;
    self.tableViewUffici.dataSource = self;
    //Ricarico la tableView perchè devo attendere i tempi della connessione
    [self.tableViewUffici reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you also provide the error. It would greatly help us to help you.

Comment: Why are you calling `reloadData` on `_tableViewUffici` instead of `self.tableViewUffici`?

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us what the error is.

Comment: "compiler found an error"... Which one?

Comment: This is the error:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UfficiViewController 0x7fc2a2dbbbb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'

Comment: Do a search on the error. It's been covered many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the storyboard, you have wired a table view to an outlet named `tableView`. Then in the view controller code you deleted it but you forgot to unwire it. Please note that this is not an error from the compiler. It's runtime error.

### Solution

1. Go to the storyboard. Click on the view controller.
2. Open *Connections Inspector* (cmd + option + 6).
3. Look for a connection with name `tableView`.
4. Delete it.

Answer (score 0):

change the

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView* tableViewUffici;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITableView* tableViewUffici;
```

This may help you.